# C# getting the HTML document from a Javascript Iframe

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to access this webpage http://www.pof.com with C# code.
I figured out that the Document element is stored in an iframe after I successfully logged in as a user and I am not familiar with how to access the document element.

All I want to do is to get the HTML format of that page which is loaded with an iframe and go to some of the links of that site.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document
```

or simply,

```
var elemVal;
if (iframeDocument) {
   elemVal= iframeDocument.getElementById('#iframe1');
}
```

Comment: +1: Note that this code assumes you want to access frame with JavaScript. May need some adaptation if called from C# using WebBrowser control (if it what OP means in "with C# code")

Comment: thnk you @AlexeiLevenkov. well, user has not clearly mentioned that he wanted it in c# controls only. since java script can be the simplest way inspite of technology, hence i suggested that.

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks for the reply, yeah I am still really new and just don't know what is the best way.  I am currently using Html-agility pack to parse the html.  I will look into WebBrowsser control.